# reading list of c++ classes

Tags: c++, class

My question is in relation to c++ classes and docs describing them.

This tutorial describes the `libtins` library and describes the `sniffer` class for performing network packet sniffing.

[libtins](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/)

However, I cannot find the class `sniffer` in the docs which are available here.

[class list docs](http://libtins.github.io/docs/latest/annotated.html)

Am I reading them correctly?

Comment: Its present in http://libtins.github.io/docs/latest/dc/db3/sniffer_8h_source.html ( Line 324 )

Answer (score 0):

Your first link shows an example program that includes

```
#include <tins/tins.h>
```

If you go to the 'files' tab in your second link, and look at that file you will see that it includes

```
 #include <tins/sniffer.h>
```

I'm pretty sure that file is what you are looking for. Here is the direct link:

http://libtins.github.io/docs/latest/dc/db3/sniffer_8h_source.html

Line 324